# Need SQL Query Help for SQL SERVER 2008 DB

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please refer the image for our table structure and expected output. I need all the rows from table 1 along with a new column that gives the count of plan number for each batch id from the second table.

[image: Table Structure and Excepted output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like a pretty simple `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT T1.[Batch Id], BatchName, Date, Status, COUNT(PlanNumber) AS PLANCOUNT
FROM Table1 T1
JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.[Batch Id] = T2.[Batch Id]
GROUP BY T1.[Batch Id], BatchName, Date, Status
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Join the tables (left join is better because it count miss rows from 1 where you have no plans), followed by a group

```
SELECT 
   T1.[Batch Id], 
   T1.[Batch Name], 
   T1.[Date], 
   T1.[Status], 
   COUNT(T2.PlanNUmber) AS PLANCOUNT
FROM
  Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.[Batch Id] = T2.[Batch Id]
GROUP BY
   T1.[Batch Id], 
   T1.[Batch Name], 
   T1.[Date], 
   T1.[Status]
```

As I stated if you do a LEFT JOIN then it will pick batches without Plans, but if you know for certain that there are no rows in Batches in T1 that have no rows in T2 then you are ok with an INNER JOIN.

Personally I prefer the first as it's covers both cases nicely.